# Deleting content of multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, methods, arraylist

I have created a program that stores three different pieces of info about an mp3.

I have a `trackNum`, `name` and `duration` `ArrayList`s.

I need to delete content from each of the `ArrayList`s using the index number, here is what I have done:

```
    //This is my method

    public void removeTrack(Integer postion){
        trackNum.remove(postion);
        name.remove(postion);
        duration.remove(postion);
    }

    //This is me using the method
    case 2:
        meth.print();
        System.out.println("Please enter the index of the track you want to remove:");
        meth.removeTrack(in.nextInt());
        break;
```

The problem I'm having, is that it's not deleting the index for each array list, for example:

Input:

```
         index    trackNum    name    duration 
           0        111         1         1
           1         2          2         2
           2         3          3         3
           3         4          4         4
```

If I enter 2, to delete index 2 for each array list.

Output:

```
         index    trackNum    name    duration 
           0        111         1         1
           1         3          2         2
           2         4          3         3
```

and if i enter 111 it will delete 111

So can someone help me to delete the content of the index for each `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Method from

```
public void removeTrack(Integer postion){
```

To

```
public void removeTrack(int postion){
```

If you use object, it will try to find object within the list. If you use primitive, its going to consider it as position and hence remove element at position.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is an object, so you'll be calling [`List.remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) - i.e., remove the passed **value**.
If you want to delete an index, you should define `position` as a primitive `int`:

```
public void removeTrack(int postion){
    trackNum.remove(postion);
    name.remove(postion);
    duration.remove(postion);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions from my side regarding your design

Instead of creating a List separately for each of the properties i.e Name, Track, and Duration, You can just create a class say SongInfo and then keep the different attributes as Instance variables in the class

You can define a List that holds only Objects of type SongInfo. This way design will be a lot better

Comment: Thanks, only just seen this sorry. I agree though, this was when I was just started programming lol